# Sorting out visa (and no visa) tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

There was a discussion in [You Are Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) today about what terminologies about cleaning up tags used for visas. Currently, we have [visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas), [visa-waiver-program](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-waiver-program), and [visa-free-entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-free-entry).

Leave your suggestions below. Vote UP if you agree and DOWN if you disagree.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions are:

- Keep [visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas) for general visa questions, primarily for ones which need to be applied for in advance.

Going by the [definition of a visa being](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/visa) "an endorsement in a passport or similar document, signifying that the document is in order and permitting its bearer to travel into or through the country of the government issuing it", I consider entry stamps to be visas too as they are endorsements that allow travellers to remain in a specific country for a limited time. Accordingly:

- Use [visa-on-arrival](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-on-arrival) for all cases where a visa can be applied for with paperwork if needed when entering a country *as well as* all cases where an entry stamp is used as a visa. Basically, if there's a stamp involved, that's a visa and deem it to have been granted on arrival.
- In case where an entry stamp is not issued, e.g., travel within Schengen member states use [visa-free-entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-free-entry). Make [visa-waiver](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-waiver) a synonym.

Answer (score 2):

[visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas) are fine, everyone knows what one is.

[visa-waiver-program](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-waiver-program) is a special case for the US only, in that it's not a visa, but it still kinda is.  However it's almost a different word entirely, if it was just called some acronym, say (VWP) we'd have used that, so I'm still happy keeping the long version.

[visa-free-entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-free-entry) - um, what? Oh right, for places that don't.  Why not just stick with [visas]?  Some questions will be 'Do I need a visa for X given I'm from y?', and others will be 'I'm from y, so I don't need one, right?' and although it's esesntailly the same question, they're going to try and do different tags if you allow both [visa-on-arrival](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-on-arrival) and [visa-free-entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-free-entry).  I'd keep it in one place for now.

---

OK, let's revise. Now that I've spelled that out, I'll rephase with my preferences:

[visa-waiver-program](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-waiver-program) is special, and I re-iterate that it needs to exist.  Perhaps as a synonym to something else. I'll come to that.

[visa-required](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-required) should be a tag.  This can be used to determine whether is required before getting there.

[visa-on-arrival](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-on-arrival) should be a tag. This is for arriving and getting a visa at the border, instantly.  [visa-waiver-program](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-waiver-program) should now be added as a synonym for this, but should definitely still exist.

[visa-free-entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-free-entry) - I don't like it, but thinking about it it makes sense to keep.

Other tags related to visas which should stay: [schengen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schengen), [eu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu), [free-travel-zone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-travel-zone) etc.  No need to add them if they don't exist, but that sort of thing should be kept for people to search on.

Comment: Sometimes trying to imagine how tags might be used and what kinds of questions might be asked leads to different answers than seeing how questions are asked and tagged in practice.

Comment: The American Visa Waiver Program actually is often abbreviated as "VWP", but we can't use that as a tag because we decided to reserve all 3-letter tags for IATA airport tags. Also, while the American program is a specific thing, the term "visa waiver" is in common use for plenty of other visa free travel agreements between arbitrary pairs of countries. I posted some examples in the chat room last night.

Comment: I think it would be best to nut out all this stuff with a bunch of people in chat during the event.

Comment: Apparently `vwp` is the airport code for [a United States Forestry Service in Bernard, Indiana](http://airport-codes.findthedata.org/l/2081/Bernard-ID-Bernard-Usfs) - so not a likely candidate for a traveller questions.

Comment: "I'm interested in hiking in forests around Bernard, Indiana - is there an airport I can use to get there or do I need a car?" ;)

Comment: I'm going to add "visa on arrival" to a few questions that specifically mention it. We can always merge it with anything else on the outcome of our future thinktank.

Comment: @pnuts it would have been back in the chat back then, or perhaps on another meta post.  Community used to have heated discussions about it back then.  But 5 years ago, so I'm not digging up a source.

Answer (score 1):

I think what might help is to dig out existing questions and see what characteristics they have. From this we can see if there are major groupings if types of questions and then we can try to characterize each with a tag for which we will have to come up with the best name.

The easy one is the broad [visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas) which covers all questions about visas and about whether you need one or not for a given county.

Now what visa-ish questions do we have where [visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas) is either inappropriate or not sufficient on its own?

**Questions found so far:**

- [Do Australian citizens still get visa-free entry for 360 days in the Republic of Georgia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/do-australian-citizens-still-get-visa-free-entry-for-360-days-in-the-republic-of)
- [Does an EU citizen need a visa to visit Australia for holidays?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/does-an-eu-citizen-need-a-visa-to-visit-australia-for-holidays)
- [Do you need to get a new ESTA when your passport is renewed?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/do-you-need-to-get-a-new-esta-when-your-passport-is-renewed)
- [Flying UK to Canada via USA. Do I need to apply for ESTA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/flying-uk-to-canada-via-usa-do-i-need-to-apply-for-esta)
- [How long can a citizen of Iran stay in Georgia (the country) as a tourist?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/how-long-can-a-citizen-of-iran-stay-in-georgia-the-country-as-a-tourist)
- [How to extend Indonesian visa on arrival (VOA) in Indonesia.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/991/how-to-extend-indonesian-visa-on-arrival-voa-in-indonesia)
- [Re-entering with the Visa Waiver Program for the USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/re-entering-with-the-visa-waiver-program-for-the-usa)
- [Transit visa on arrival in Kazakhstan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/transit-visa-on-arrival-in-kazakhstan)
- [Visa-on-arrival scheme in Philippines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/480/visa-on-arrival-scheme-in-philippines)
- [What is the minimum passport expiry period when travelling to USA on an ESTA authorization from a previous visit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/862/what-is-the-minimum-passport-expiry-period-when-travelling-to-usa-on-an-esta-aut)